# Particles attracting each other not working properly

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, simulation

I'm trying to make particles attract each other in Python. It works a bit but they always move to the top-left corner (0;0).

A year ago, CodeParade released a [video about a game of life he made with particles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_zmZ23grXE). I thought it was cool and wanted to recreate it myself in Python. It wasn't that difficult but I have a problem. Every time some particles are near enough to attract each other, they get a bit closer but at the same time they "run" to the upper-left corner which happens to be (0;0). I first thought I wasn't applying the attraction effect correctly but after re-reading it multiple times I haven't found any errors. Does somebody have any idea why it doesn't work as expected ?

/ Here is the code /

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pygame, random, time
import numpy as np

attraction = [  [-2.6,8.8,10.2,0.7],
                [4.1,-3.3,-3.1,4.4],
                [0.6,3.7,-0.4,5.1],
                [-7.8,0.3,0.3,0.0]]

minR = [[100.0,100.0,100.0,100.0],
        [100.0,100.0,100.0,100.0],
        [100.0,100.0,100.0,100.0],
        [100.0,100.0,100.0,100.0]]

maxR = [[41.7,16.4,22.1,15.0],
        [16.4,41.7,32.0,75.1],
        [22.1,32.0,55.7,69.9],
        [15.0,75.1,69.9,39.5]]

colors = [  (200,50,50),
            (200,100,200),
            (100,255,100),
            (50,100,100)]

#Rouge
#Violet
#Vert
#Cyan

particles = []

#Number of particles
numberParticles = 5

#Width
w = 500

#Height
h = 500

#Radius of particles
r = 4

#Rendering speed
speed = 0.05

#Attraction speed factor
speedFactor = 0.01

#Min distance factor
minRFactor = 0.1

#Max distance factor
maxRFactor = 2

#Attraction factor
attractionFactor = 0.01

def distance(ax, ay, bx, by):
    return intg((ax - bx)**2 + (ay - by)**2)

def intg(x):
    return int(round(x))

def display(plan):
    #Fill with black
    #Momentarily moved to main
    #pygame.Surface.fill(plan,(0,0,0))

    #For each particle, draw it
    for particle in particles:
        pygame.draw.circle(plan,colors[particle[0]],(particle[1],particle[2]),r)

    #Update display
    pygame.display.flip()

def update(particles):
    newParticles = []

    for particleIndex in xrange(len(particles)):
        typeId, x, y = particles[particleIndex]

        othersX = [[],[],[],[]]
        othersY = [[],[],[],[]]

        #For every other particles
        for otherParticle in particles[0:particleIndex]+particles[particleIndex+1:]:

            otherTypeId, otherX, otherY = otherParticle


            """
            #Draw minR and maxR of attraction for each color
            pygame.draw.circle(screen,colors[otherTypeId],(x,y),intg(minR[typeId][otherTypeId] * minRFactor),1)
            pygame.draw.circle(screen,colors[otherTypeId],(x,y),intg(maxR[typeId][otherTypeId] * maxRFactor),1)
            """

            #If otherParticle is between minR and maxR from (x;y)
            if (minR[typeId][otherTypeId] * minRFactor)**2 <= distance(x,y,otherX,otherY) <= (maxR[typeId][otherTypeId] * maxRFactor)**2:

                #Append otherParticle's coordinates to othersX and othersY respectively
                othersX[otherTypeId].append(otherX)
                othersY[otherTypeId].append(otherY)

        #Take the average attractions for each color
        othersX = [np.mean(othersX[i]) * attraction[typeId][i] * attractionFactor for i in xrange(len(othersX)) if othersX[i] != []]
        othersY = [np.mean(othersY[i]) * attraction[typeId][i] * attractionFactor for i in xrange(len(othersY)) if othersY[i] != []]

        #If not attracted, stay in place
        if othersX == []:
            newX = x

        else:

            #Take the average attraction
            avgX = np.mean(othersX)

            #Determine the new x position
            newX = x - (x - avgX) * speedFactor

            #If out of screen, warp
            if newX > w:
                newX -= w

            elif newX < 0:
                newX += w

        #If not attracted, stay in place
        if othersY == []:
            newY = y

        else:

            #Take the average attraction
            avgY = np.mean(othersY)

            #Determine the new y position
            newY = y - (y - avgY) * speedFactor

            #If out of screen, warp
            if newY > h:
                newY -= h

            elif newY < 0:
                newY += h

        #Append updated particle to newParticles
        newParticles.append([typeId,intg(newX),intg(newY)])

    return newParticles

if __name__ == "__main__":

    #Initialize pygame screen
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode([w,h])

    #Particle = [type,posX,posY]
    #Create randomly placed particles of random type
    for x in xrange(numberParticles):
        particles.append([random.randint(0,3),random.randint(0,w),random.randint(0,h)])

    display(screen)

    #Wait a bit
    time.sleep(1)

    while True:
        #raw_input()
        #Fill the screen with black
        pygame.Surface.fill(screen,(0,0,0))

        #Update particles
        particles = update(particles)

        #Display particles
        display(screen)

        #Wait a bit
        time.sleep(speed)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in the lines:

> ```py
> othersX = [np.mean(othersX[i]) * attraction[typeId][i] * attractionFactor for i in range(len(othersX)) if othersX[i] != []]
> othersY = [np.mean(othersY[i]) * attraction[typeId][i] * attractionFactor for i in range(len(othersY)) if othersY[i] != []]
> ```

`othersX` and `othersY` should be positions, but since the coordinates are multiplied by `attraction[typeId][i] * attractionFactor`, the coordinates are shifted to top left.

This can be evaluated with ease, by omitting the factors:

```py
othersX = [np.mean(othersX[i]) for i in range(len(othersX)) if othersX[i] != []]
othersY = [np.mean(othersY[i]) for i in range(len(othersY)) if othersY[i] != []]
```

An option is to use vectors form (`x`, `y`) to (`otherX`, `otherY`) rather than positions:

```c
for otherParticle in particles[0:particleIndex]+particles[particleIndex+1:]:
    otherTypeId, otherX, otherY = otherParticle

    if (minR[typeId][otherTypeId] * minRFactor)**2 <= distance(x,y,otherX,otherY) <= (maxR[typeId][otherTypeId] * maxRFactor)**2:

        # Append otherParticle's coordinates to othersX and othersY respectively
        othersX[otherTypeId].append(otherX - x)
        othersY[otherTypeId].append(otherY - y)

othersX = [np.mean(othersX[i]) * attraction[typeId][i] * attractionFactor for i in range(len(othersX)) if othersX[i] != []]
othersY = [np.mean(othersY[i]) * attraction[typeId][i] * attractionFactor for i in range(len(othersY)) if othersY[i] != []]
```

Of course you've to adapt the calculation of the new positions, too:

```py
avgX = np.mean(othersX)
newX = x + avgX * speedFactor
```

```py
avgY = np.mean(othersY)
newY = y + avgY * speedFactor
```

---

As mentioned in the other answer, you should use floating point numbers for the calculations:

```py
def distance(ax, ay, bx, by):
    # return intg((ax - bx)**2 + (ay - by)**2)
    return (ax - bx)**2 + (ay - by)**2
```

```py
# newParticles.append([typeId,intg(newX),intg(newY)])
newParticles.append([typeId, newX, newY])
```

But round to integral coordinates when you draw the circles:

```py
for particle in particles:
    # pygame.draw.circle(plan,colors[particle[0]],(particle[1],particle[2]),r)
    pygame.draw.circle(plan,colors[particle[0]],(intg(particle[1]),intg(particle[2])),r)
```

Comment: But I can't multiply `attraction[typeId][i]` with the `avgX` and `avgY` because it depends on the particle's type. For example, green particles will attract red particles more than purple ones.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. I'll try something and give you some updates.

Comment: @LordBaryhobal I've add a possible solution to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It might be this line here:

```
newParticles.append([typeId,intg(newX),intg(newY)])
```

You calculated the position of you particles with high precision earlier, but then the `intg()` will round all of those numbers down towards 0 before you save it to `newparticles`.  Over time this will skew things towards `[0,0]`.

How I would fix this is by keeping the data in your `particles` and `newparticles` as floating point precision, only do the rounding when you have to put things on screen.  This way the high accuracy you use will be kept from one timestep to the next.

Comment: This was my first guess, too. But I tried it and I figured out that this is not the issue.